# Surviving in the sunlight?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I know in Requiem there are ways to be a vampire and walk during the day without being harmed. I was wondering if there is a way to do this in Old World of Darkness as well. Magic, tech, miscellaneous, whatever it may be. Just a way that a vampire can either be immune to the sun or move in daylight without being harmed?

Comment: See http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12734/can-a-vampire-survive-sunlight-exposure

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? This question is specifically asking about Old World of Darkness, while the linked question is about Vampire: the Masquerade.

Comment: Vampire: the Masquerade is the OWOD. 
Vampire the Requiem is the NWOD.
Both questions are for the OWOD.

Answer (score 2):

Tech way:

1. be awake during day
2. go to your garage and get into the sun-proof van
3. have your ghoul drive you wherever you need to get to
4. ...
5. PROFIT!

One could also argue that high-SPF sunscreen should add to soaking rolls (or decrease sunlight strength).

Comment: Smart ass answer, but i like it!